# Sort vector keeping NAs position in R

Tags: r, sorting, na, missing-data

**Problem 1** (solved)

How can I sort vector `DoB`:

```
DoB <- c(NA, 9, NA, 2, 1, NA)
```

while keeping the `NA`s in the same position?

I would like to get:

```
> DoB
[1] NA 1 NA 2 9 NA
```

I have tried this (borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493969/how-to-insert-elements-into-a-vector))

```
NAs_index <- which(is.na(DoB))
DoB <- sort(DoB, na.last = NA)
for(i in 0:(length(NAs_index)-1)) 
  DoB <- append(DoB, NA, after=(NAs_index[i+1]+i))
```

but

```
> DoB
[1]  1 NA  2  9 NA NA
```

> Answer is
>
> DoB[!is.na(DoB)] <- sort(DoB)
>
> Thanks to @BigDataScientist and @akrun

Now, **Problem 2**

Say, I have a vector `id`

```
id <- 1:6
```

That I would also like to sort by the same principle, so that the values of `id` are ordered according to `order(DoB)`, but keeping the `NA`s fixed in the same position?:

```
> id
[1] 1 5 3 4 2 6
```

Comment: are/can `id` and `DoB` be stored in a common `data.frame()` or `matrix()`?

Comment: yes, they could

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
DoB[!is.na(DoB)] <- sort(DoB)
```

**Edit:** Concerning the follow up question in the comments:

You can use `order()` for that and take care of the `NA`s with the `na.last` parameter,..

```
data <- data.frame(DoB = c(NA, 9, NA, 2, 1, NA), id = 1:6)
data$id[!is.na(data$DoB)] <- order(data$DoB, na.last = NA)
data$DoB[!is.na(data$DoB)] <- sort(data$DoB)
```

Comment: Can I expand a bit: what if I wanted to order a second vector (id = 1:6) by the same principle (to have `id` be 1 5 3 4 2 6)?

Comment: you mean: `id[c(1,5,3,4,2,6)]` ? (however, we shouldnt get too unrelated from the original question, in the follow up comments :) )

Comment: I edited the question to make this second part clearer, I didn't thin kit was worth opening a second question, but I can also do that if it would be more appropriate. My Problem 2 is basically, how can I use `order` to return a vector of the ordered indices while keeping the `NA`s fixed in the same position?

Comment: you are right the questions belong "together",...hope the edit helps!

Comment: awesome, you're a :star: !

Answer (score 2):

We create a logical index and then do the `sort`

```
i1 <- is.na(DoB)
DoB[!i1] <- sort(DoB[!i1])
DoB
#[1] NA  1 NA  2  9 NA
```