# Insert elements into a vector at a given position, a given number of times

Tags: r, vector

I have vector `x <- c(1:50)`, and I want to insert `y <- c(1,2)` every 10nth position 5 times.

```
x <- c(1:50)
y <- c(1,2)
z <- c(seq(10,50,10))
```

The product has to be like this:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 1 2 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 1 2 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 1 2 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 1 2 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 1 2
```

I have tried with append, but it doesn't use "times"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can `split` the 'x' into a `list` of `vector` based on a grouping index created with ``` %/%``, concatenate ( ```c`) with the 'y' using 'Map` and `unlist` the `list` to get the `vector`

```
unlist(Map(c, split(x, (x-1)%/%10), list(y)), use.names = FALSE)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20  1  2 21
#[26] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30  1  2 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40  1  2 41 42
#[51] 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50  1  2
```

Comment: what if x and y are character vectors?

Comment: @JoseVictorZambrana  Then, we do it based on the sequence of 'x' i.e. `split(x, (seq_along(x)-1)%/% 10)`

Comment: Sorry!   split(x, (seq_along(x)-1)%/% 10) doesn't work, it gives me a list of 5 groups

Comment: @JoseVictorZambrana  I meant to use it with the `unlist(Map` because other parts are not changing i.e. `unlist(Map(c, split(x, (seq_along(x)-1)%/%10), list(y)), use.names = FALSE)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use append if you use a loop ala [How to insert elements into a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493969/how-to-insert-elements-into-a-vector)

```
x <- 1:50
y <- c(1,2)
z <- c(seq(10,50,10))

 for(i in 0:(length(z)-1)) {
   out <- append(x, y, after=(z[i+1]+i))
 }

 out
```

But I like akrun's suggestion

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is obtained by transforming x into a 10X5 matrix and then incrementally `rbind`ing 1 and 2. `c` is used to return a vector.

```
c(rbind(rbind(matrix(x, 10), 1), 2))
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20  1  2 21 22 23 24
[29] 25 26 27 28 29 30  1  2 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40  1  2 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
[57] 49 50  1  2
```

This can be generalize to more than 2 values by putting them in a list and using `Reduce`:

```
c(Reduce(rbind, list(matrix(x, 10), 1, 2)))
```

Following @akrun's comment, you can use y in place a 1,2 in the line above with

```
c(Reduce(rbind, append(list(matrix(x, 10)), y)))
```

or

```
c(Reduce(rbind, c(list(matrix(x, 10)), as.list(y))))
```