# Replace one element in vector with multiple elements

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I have a vector where I want to replace one element with multiple element, I am able to replace with one but not multuiple, can anyone help?

For example I have

```
data <- c('a', 'x', 'd')
> data
[1] "a" "x" "d"
```

I want to replace `"x"` with `"b", "c"` to get

```
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

However

```
gsub('x', c('b', 'c'), data)
```

gives me

```
[1] "a" "b" "d"
Warning message:
In gsub("x", c("b", "c"), data) :
  argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will 
be used
```

Comment: Some of these may apply as well: [How to insert elements into a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493969/how-to-insert-elements-into-a-vector)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I would tackle it:

```
data <- c('a', 'x', 'd')
lst <- as.list(data)
unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) if(x == "x") c("b", "c") else x))
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

We're making use of the fact that list-structures are more flexible than atomic vectors. We can replace a length-1 list-element with a length>1 element and then unlist the result to go back to an atomic vector.

Since you want to replace exact matches of "x" I prefer not to use `sub`/`gsub` in this case.

Comment: The use of `lapply` here is probably quite a bit slower than vectorised comparison and list splicing, as done in efbbrown’s answer attempt.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, that's probably true. I haven't said anything about performance (and neither did OP) but I'm positive that this approach returns the correct answer when it finishes.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this , although I believe the accepted answer is great:

```
unlist(strsplit(gsub("x", "b c", data), split = " "))
```

**Logic**: Replacing "x" with "b c" with space and then doing the strsplit, once its splitted we can convert is again back to vector using unlist.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky of a problem because in your replacement you also want to grow your vector. That being said, I believe this should work:

```
replacement <- c("b","c")

new_data <- rep(data, times = ifelse(data=="x", length(replacement), 1))
new_data[new_data=="x"] <- replacement

new_data
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

This will also work if you have multiple `"x"`s in your vector like:

```
data <- c("a","x","d","x")
```

Comment: Curious as to why this was downvoted. If someone wants to elaborate on why this wrong, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
data <- c('a', 'x', 'd')
pattern <- "x"
replacement <- c("b", "c")

sub_one_for_many <- function(pattern, replacement, x) {
  removal_index <- which(x == pattern)
  if (removal_index > 1) {
    result <- c(x[1:(removal_index-1)], replacement, x[(removal_index+1):length(x)])
  } else if (removal_index == 1) {
    result <- c(replacement, x[2:length(x)])
  }
  return(result)
}

answer <- sub_one_for_many(pattern, replacement, data)
```

Output:

```
> answer
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Comment: I believe this will also only work if you have 1 `"x"`. If there is > 1 it will only replace the first.

Comment: I agree with both of you, changed the function name accordingly.

Comment: @docendodiscimus fixed that too

Comment: Yeah you're right about the error, is fixed. The question did not ask for a function that could replace multiple x-values, just a function that could replace one element with multiple values.