# Create dataframe based on matching

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I want to create a df in R with two variables, they have different number of rows. This is an abstract example: I want to match a 3 to "Fail" (without writing in manually, I know that I could just write the 3 in a on the third place). So first assign 3 to Fail, than match 1 to Test, 2 to Test, 4 to Success and 5 to Test by skipping Fail.

```
a <- c(1,2,4,5)
b <- c("Test", "Test", "Fail", "Success", "Test")
data.frame(a,b)
```

So the following steps would be important:

1st: find string "Fail": assign a certain value to it (here 3)

2nd: create a df with a and b

3rd: final result should look like this:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Test |
| 2 | Test |
| 3 | Fail |
| 4 | Success |
| 5 | Test |

Comment: what determines a test, fail and success? how is `a` generated

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493969/how-to-insert-elements-into-a-vector)

Answer (score 1):

```r
idx <- which(b == "Fail")
a <- append(a, idx, after = idx - 1)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

data.frame(a, b)
  a       b
1 1    Test
2 2    Test
3 3    Fail
4 4 Success
5 5    Test
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I wanted, does this work for multiple Rows as well? For example if I would like to have "Test" == 1 always? In this case a would be something like: a=c(3,4). 3 for Fail and 4 for Success

Comment: With a few tweaks it should work yes

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create both vectors. If you are going with indexes, you can just do,

```
data.frame(a = seq_along(b), b = b)

  a       b
1 1    Test
2 2    Test
3 3    Fail
4 4 Success
5 5    Test
```