# How to add "NA" into a vector where the positions are specifically identified?

Tags: r, vector, sequence, na

Suppose we have a vector:

```
x<-c(1,3,4,6,7)
```

And we have another vector that specifies the positions of NAs:

```
NAs<-c(2,5)
```

How can I add NA to the vector `x` in the 2nd and 5th index so `x` becomes

```
x
1 NA 3 4 NA 6 7
```

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Insert elements into a vector at particular indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493969/insert-elements-into-a-vector-at-particular-indexes)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this?

```
> replace(sort(c(x, NAs)), NAs, NA)
[1]  1 NA  3  4 NA  6  7
```

or a safer solution

```
> v <- c(x, NAs)

> replace(rep(NA, length(v)), !seq_along(v) %in% NAs, x)
[1]  1 NA  3  4 NA  6  7
```

Answer (score 2):

With a `for` loop, using `append`:

```r
for (i in sort(NAs)) x <- append(x, NA, after = i - 1)
#[1]  1 NA  3  4 NA  6  7
```